# Typescript Module not found Can't resolve

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm building a react + typescript app in which I created a module with interfaces that are used all around my project's classes. My IDE resolves these interfaces fine but webpack always sends the following error. I tried different things but can't get that one to go away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
ERROR in ./assets/src/Pages/Login.tsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'seeyouftp' in 'var/www/app/assets/src/Pages'
 @ ./assets/src/Pages/Login.tsx 43:18-38
 @ ./assets/src/Config/App.tsx
 @ ./assets/entries/bundle.js
```

My definition file is here

```
|— definitions
     |— types.d.ts
|— entries
|— fonts
|— less
|— src
```

Excerpt of my definition file

```
declare module 'seeyouftp' {
  interface User {
    admin: boolean;
    roles: string[];
    username: string;
  }

  enum AuthStates {
    success = 'success',
    error = 'error'
  }
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "baseUrl": "./assets",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2019",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./assets/definitions/types.d.ts",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./assets/src/**/*",
    "./assets/definitions/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I import the created interfaces like so:

`import { Item, PlayableMedia } from 'seeyouftp';`

Comment: Please include the code where you import `seeyouftp `

Comment: Is `seeyouftp` npm package or your file? if your file, where is it located?

Comment: `seeyouftp` is not an npm package. It's only the name of the module contained in my `types.d.ts`file. It's declared like so: `declare module 'seeyouftp'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The error message was actually very misleading, and looks like a typescript bug.
It appears that `enums` can't be exported directly, it seems necessary to use a  `const` to be able to export them correctly.

So I modified my `enum` declaration like so

```
declare module 'seeyouftp' {

  // exporting a const instead of 
  export const enum AuthStates {
    success = 'success',
    error = 'error'
  }
}
```

Everything works now but that error message is very, very bad and time consuming

Comment: Just a random comment to say thank you so much for following up and answering your post. I ran into the same issue and had a hunch enum was the culprit, since it was the only file that wasn't importing properly from my TS project.

Comment: i don't think it's a bug as it is still resolvable to a types file but this variation is necessary for my project which exports eslint rules as javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `seeyouftp` (I assum that `seeyouftp` is your js module name) folder under `/definitions` and have `types.d.ts` inside `/definitions/seeyouftp` like structure below

```
|— definitions
 |—seeyouftp
  |— index.d.ts
|— entries
|— fonts
|— less
|— src
```

And update your `tsconfig`

```
"typeRoots": [
  "./assets/definitions",
  "./node_modules/@types"
],
```

Comment: when you say 'I assum that seeyouftp is your js module name' do you mean the `name` field in `package.json` ?

Comment: The name you normally use to import with js.
And one more thing need to be updated in `tsconfig` file. Please check my updated comment and try it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "The name you normally use to import with js". I import the types using this kind of import, is it what you mean ?
`import { Item, PlayableMedia } from 'seeyouftp';`

Comment: Yes. So I think `seeyouftp` is correct name. Did you try to update `tsconfig`?

Comment: Yes, actually my `tsconfig` was already setup this way

Comment: I just notice that your file is `types.d.ts` could you try to change to `index.d.ts`. Check my updated comment again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216435/discussion-between-titiyoyo-and-tony-nguyen).

Answer (score 1):

Try to export the declarations, and see if that makes a difference:

```js
declare module 'seeyouftp' {
export  interface User {
    admin: boolean;
    roles: string[];
    username: string;
  }

export  enum AuthStates {
    success = 'success',
    error = 'error'
  }
```

Comment: I tried exporting every interface in the module but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a webpack issue, you have to update your webpack config. Webpack needs to be told where to find the module `seeyouftp`:

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    // Add an alias
    alias: {
      'seeyouftp': path.resolve(__dirname, 'definitions/types.d.ts')
    }
  }
};
```

For the path to the file `types.d.ts` I assumed your webpack configuration is located next to the `definitions` folder.

[Here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) is the associated webpack documentation.